# Set minor tick label spacing on a log axis, and change colorbar tick label size

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, colorbar

I am trying to create a plot but I just want the ticklabels to show as shown where the log scale is shown as above. I only want the minor ticklabel for 50, 500 and 2000 to show. Is there anyway to specify the minor tick labels to show?? I have been trying to figure this out for a bit but haven't found a good solution. All I can think of is to get the minorticklabels() and set the fontsize to 0. This is shown below the first snippet of code. I was hoping there was a more clean solution.

The other thing is changing the size of the ticklabels in the colorbar which I haven't figured out. If anyone knows of a way to do this please let me know because I don't see a method in colorbar that easily does this.

First code:

```
fig = figure(figto)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
actShape = activationTrace.shape
semitones = arange(actShape[1])
freqArray = arange(actShape[0])
X,Y = meshgrid(self.testFreqArray,self.testFreqArray)
Z = sum(activationTrace[:,:,beg:end],axis=2)
surf = ax.contourf(X,Y,Z, 8, cmap=cm.jet)
ax.set_position([0.12,0.15,.8,.8])
ax.set_ylabel('Log Frequency (Hz)')
ax.set_xlabel('Log Frequency (Hz)')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%d'))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.tick_params(axis='both',reset=False,which='both',length=8,width=2)
self.plotSetAxisLabels(ax,22)
self.plotSetAxisTickLabels(ax,18)
cbar = fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=20, fraction=.12,pad=.02)
cbar.set_label('Activation',size=18)
return ax, cbar
```

[image]

Second Code:

```
fig = figure(figto)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
actShape = activationTrace.shape
semitones = arange(actShape[1])
freqArray = arange(actShape[0])
X,Y = meshgrid(self.testFreqArray,self.testFreqArray)
Z = sum(activationTrace[:,:,beg:end],axis=2)
surf = ax.contourf(X,Y,Z, 8, cmap=cm.jet)
ax.set_position([0.12,0.15,.8,.8])
ax.set_ylabel('Log Frequency (Hz)')
ax.set_xlabel('Log Frequency (Hz)')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%d'))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%d'))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.tick_params(axis='both',reset=False,which='both',length=8,width=2)
self.plotSetAxisLabels(ax,22)
self.plotSetAxisTickLabels(ax,18)
cbar = fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=20, fraction=.12,pad=.02)
cbar.set_label('Activation',size=18)
count = 0
for i in ax.xaxis.get_minorticklabels():
    if (count%4 == 0):
        i.set_fontsize(12)
    else:
        i.set_fontsize(0)
    count+=1
for i in ax.yaxis.get_minorticklabels():
    if (count%4 == 0):
        i.set_fontsize(12)
    else:
        i.set_fontsize(0)
    count+=1
return ax, cbar
```

[image]

For the colorbar:
Another quick question if you don't mind because trying to figure it out but not entirely sure. I want to use scientific notation which I can get with ScalarFormatter. How do I set the number of decimal places and the multiplier?? I'd like it to be like 8x10^8 or .8x10^9 to save space instead of putting all those zeros. I figure there is multiple ways to do this inside the axes object but what do you reckon is the best way. I can't figure out how to change the notation when changing to the ScalarFormatter.

For the chart:
Also, my data has points starting at 46 and then at successive multiplies of that multiplied by 2^(1/12) so 46,49,50,55,58,61...3132. These are all rounded but lie close to the 2^(1/12). I decided it better to place major tickers close to these numbers. Is the best way to use the fixed formatter and use a ticker every 15 or so in the freqArray. Then use a minor ticker at every other frequency. Can I do this and still maintain a log axis??

Answer (score 156, accepted):

1. Use `FixedLocator` to statically define explicit tick locations.
2. Colorbar `cbar` will have an `.ax` attribute that will provide access to the usual axis methods including tick formatting. This is not a reference to an `axes` (e.g. `ax1`, `ax2`, etc.).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = np.arange(10,3000,100)
y = np.arange(10,3000,100)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = np.random.random(X.shape)*8000000
surf = ax.contourf(X,Y,Z, 8, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
ax.set_ylabel('Log Frequency (Hz)')
ax.set_xlabel('Log Frequency (Hz)')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(plt.FormatStrFormatter('%d'))
# defining custom minor tick locations:
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(plt.FixedLocator([50,500,2000]))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.tick_params(axis='both',reset=False,which='both',length=8,width=2)
cbar = fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=20, fraction=.12,pad=.02)
cbar.set_label('Activation',size=18)
# access to cbar tick labels:
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=5) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Edit**

If you want the tick marls, but you want to selectively show the labels, I see nothing wrong with your iteration, except I might use `set_visible` instead of making the fontsize zero.

You might enjoy finer control using a `FuncFormatter` where you can use the value or position of the tick to decide whether it gets shown:

```
def show_only_some(x, pos):
    s = str(int(x))
    if s[0] in ('2','5'):
        return s
    return ''

ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(show_only_some))
```

Comment: That's good stuff mate. I didn't think to use set_visible here but that is better than setting the font to size 0 because it is still at least one pixel when you do that. I want the tick marks there so the FixedLocator wouldn't work in this case but I do like the looks of the FuncFormatter. I'll stick with what I got for now but may give that a go next time.

For the FuncFormatter does it always take the two parameters in that order (value, tickposition).

Comment: Already answered my own question about FuncFormatter so no worries on that. Thanks heaps. Actually just implemented FuncFormatter because almost easier and like the extreme flexibility if I need to change it in the future makes it real easy.

Comment: Posted the question above so all can see it. Relates to getting scientific notation and specifying the number of significant digits in it. Cheers,

Comment: @Paul is it possible to force the colorbar to show numbers? I am getting only the colored strip with no labels.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @Paul I created the following function:

```
def get_formatter_function(allowed_values, datatype='float'):
    """returns a function, which only allows allowed_values as axis tick labels"""
    def hide_others(value, pos):
        if value in allowed_values:
            if datatype == 'float':
                return value
            elif datatype == 'int':
                return int(value)
        return ''
    return hide_others
```

Which is a bit more flexible.