# Python matplotlib decrease size of colorbar labels

Tags: python, attributes, matplotlib, label, colorbar

I need your help! I have a plotting code which is the following:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

imax1 = ax1.imshow(data,interpolation = 'nearest', origin = 'lower',cmap=cm.jet)#plot
cbar = plt.colorbar(imax1, extend='neither', spacing='proportional',
                orientation='vertical', shrink=0.7, format="%.0f")
cbar.set_label(r"ET [mm/month]", size=10)

titlestr = "Evapotranspiration in mm/month"
plt.title(titlestr)
#plt.xlabel("Longitude")
#plt.ylabel("Latitude")
imax1.set_clim(0,60)
labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax1.get_xticklabels()]
for ii in range(np.shape(labels)[0]):
    labels[ii] = str(grid_lon[75*ii/np.shape(labels)[0]])

ax1.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation = 45, ha='right', size = 10)

labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax1.get_yticklabels()]
for ii in range(np.shape(labels)[0]):
    labels[ii] = str(grid_lat[75*ii/np.shape(labels)[0]])

ax1.set_yticklabels(labels, size = 10)

pngname = "./out/2d_"+variable+"_"+mm+".png"
print "save ", pngname
plt.savefig(pngname, dpi=None, facecolor='w', edgecolor='w',
    orientation='portrait', papertype=None, format=None,
    transparent=False, bbox_inches=None, pad_inches=0.1)


print "plot finished"
```

I would like to set the label size of the colorbar labels (e.g. 0,10,20,...60) to size of 10 or smaller. This will probably go into the line "imax1.set_clim(0,60). Any ideas? I'd be also interested to print information of the imax1 object to command line. How could I do that? E.g. available attributes and functions of imax1.

I deeply appreciate your help!

Comment: Partial answer: `print dir(imax1)` will give you information regarding available attributes and functions of `imax1`.

Comment: great thanks, I implemented the lower one.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Aha! Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6568248/1062948):

```
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=10)
```

P.S. Upvote [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6568248/943773) answer and give Paul some love!

Comment: Note: `cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize='xx-small')` also works

Comment: Is there a way to do this through rcParams?

Comment: Note2: this doesn't change colorbar label font size; in addition, you also need to run: cbar.set_label('my label', size='xx-small')

Answer (score 3):

If you are here because you're trying to increase font size, but some numbers disappear because of big size with the above answer, you can do

```
cbar = plt.colorbar()
for t in cbar.ax.get_yticklabels():
     t.set_fontsize(20)
```