# How to give Matplolib imshow plot colorbars a label

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

We can give x and y axes labels for the main axes. Is there any way to similarly give a color bar a label? Alternately, is there any way to append a unit to one or more colorbar ticks?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567724/matplotlib-so-log-axis-only-has-minor-tick-mark-labels-at-specified-points-also/6568248#6568248

Comment: In short, `cbar = fig.colorbar(heatmap)`
`cbar.set_label('Label name',size=18)`

Comment: @qmorgan You should post that as an answer.  There is enough other stuff going on in the linked question it is worth having a simple answer.

Comment: @tcaswell OK, good to know! I'm still learning the etiquette of what should be answers and what should be comments - is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 7):

Like many axis objects, `colorbar()` has a `set_label()` method:

```
cbar = fig.colorbar(heatmap) 
cbar.set_label('Label name',size=18)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. "Object has no attribute 'set_label'".

Comment: At least for current versions of Matplotlib it should: [http://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html#matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase.set_label]

Answer (score 0):

You use annotate to place text just about anywhere and add an arrow to what it refers to see some examples [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/annotation_demo.html).